# Setting PathType in Xcode 4 TemplateInfo.plist relative to SDK

Tags: xcode4.2

I have created an Xcode 4 project template for iOS that needs to reference sqlite3.dylib. I can get the template to create a valid project if I set the PathType to Absolute for sqlite3.dylib in the Definitions element of the template.

I would like to be able to define the PathType to be relative to the SDK, can anybody offer suggestions as to what the correct PathType is to make the library reference relative to the SDK.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one took me a couple of hours. I also faced the same problem and without any documentation from Apple it was nearly impossible to figure out. I did some reverse engineering on the XCode binaries and I found an evidence in the `Xcode3UI` binary. They defined the following (internal) enum:

```
_PBXSourceTree_Absolute
_PBXSourceTree_BuildProduct
_PBXSourceTree_CurrentSDK
_PBXSourceTree_DeveloperDir
_PBXSourceTree_Group
_PBXSourceTree_Project
```

I tested it and definitely it was the case. Following are **ALL** valid values for PathType:

- **Absolute** (Equivalent to "Absolute Path")
- **BuildProduct** (Equivalent to "Relative to Build Products")
- **CurrentSDK** (Equivalent to "Relative to SDK")
- **DeveloperDir** (Equivalent to "Relative to Developer Directory")
- **Group** (Equivalent to "Relative to Group", but be careful no relative definition is allowed)
- **Project** (Equivalent to "Relative to Project")

I think you are very interested in the "**CurrentSDK**" value.

Hope this helps & Regards, Kristian

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've resolved it:

```
<key>libsqlite3.dylib</key>
            <dict>
                    <key>Path</key>
                    <string>/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib</string>
                    <key>PathType</key>
                    <string>Absolute</string>
                    <key>FileType</key>
                    <string>wrapper.framework</string>
            </dict>
```

It's not from SDK dir, but works well for  iOS 4.x and 5.x simulators.

Well, and if you really want it from SDK, add this to your TemplateInfo.plist:

```
                <key>Targets</key>
            <array>
                    <dict>
                            <key>BuildPhases</key>
                            <array>
                                    <dict>
                                            <key>Class</key>
                                            <string>Sources</string>
                            </dict>
                            <dict>
                                    <key>Class</key>
                                    <string>Frameworks</string>
                            </dict>
                            <dict>
                                    <key>Class</key>
                                    <string>ShellScript</string>
                                    <key>ShellPath</key>
                                    <string>/bin/bash</string>
                                    <key>ShellScript</key>
                                    <string>
                   grep &#39;/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib; sourceTree = &quot;&lt;absolute&gt;&quot;&#39; &quot;$PROJECT_DIR/$PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj&quot; &amp;&amp;
                                    sed  -i -e &#39;s|/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib; sourceTree = &quot;&lt;absolute&gt;&quot;|usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib; sourceTree = SDKROOT|g&#39; &quot;$PROJECT_DIR/$PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj&quot;
```

The only inconvenience: you need to build a project generated from the template before the change takes effect. After the first build is done, you'll need to close/open the prj.